# Leetcode 1584. How to make my Kruskal&Union Find algorithm faster?

Tags: java, algorithm, union-find

The question was on Leetcode [1584. Min Cost to Connect All Points.](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-cost-to-connect-all-points/) My answer to this question is:

```
class Solution {
    public int minCostConnectPoints(int[][] points) {
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < points.length; j++){
                int dist = Math.abs(points[i][0] - points[j][0]) + Math.abs(points[i][1] - points[j][1]);
                list.add(new int[]{i,j,dist});
            }
        }
        list.sort((int a[], int b[]) -> a[2] - b[2]);
        UnionFindSet uf = new UnionFindSet(points.length);
        int totalCost = 0;
        for(int edges[] : list){
            if(uf.Find(edges[0]) != uf.Find(edges[1])){
                uf.Union(edges[0],edges[1]);
                totalCost += edges[2];
            }
        }
        return totalCost;
    }
}

class UnionFindSet {
    public final int[] parents;

    UnionFindSet(int size) {
        this.parents = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.parents[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public int Find(int x) {
        if (this.parents[x] != x) {
            this.parents[x] = Find(this.parents[x]);
        }
        return this.parents[x];
    }

    public void Union(int x, int y) {
        this.parents[Find(y)] = Find(x);
    }
}
```

My answer can pass all the test cases but the speed is extremely slow. Any idea how could I improve my code to make it faster? One of my guesses is maybe the nested for loop to calculate the Manhattan Distance is expensive, but I don't know how to omit or replace it.
Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution already seems to be implemented (rather) efficiently. My only advice is to rename `Find` and `Union` to `find` and `union`, respectively (Java style prefers lowercase chars at the first verb of a method name).

In `UnionFindSet`, you have

```
public final int[] parents;
```

I suggest you hide it by the `private` keyword instead of `public`.

In case you, in fact, seek for greater efficiency, take a look a [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Perhaps it makes sense to implement all the discussed implementations of the disjoint set data structure and benchmark them all in order to find the fastest version.